# Django: dependencies reference nonexistent parent node for an installed app

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm using a third party Django app ([github link](https://github.com/djaodjin/djaodjin-saas)) in my project and trying to create a one-to-one field reference to one of its models.

```
Organization = saas.models.Organization # Saas is my installed app


class OrganizationProfile(TimeStampedModel): # TimeStampedModel is imported from django_extensions.db.models
    organization = models.OneToOneField(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    display_name = fields.CharField(max_length=127)
    # other fields
```

When I make the migrations, there are two files generated

1. `0013_auto_20200415_1919.py` in the site-packages directory of my venv `saas/migrations/0013_auto_20200415_1924.py`
2. `0001_initial.py` in my own application where I've defined this one-to-one relationship. This file has a dependency to `('saas', '0013_auto_20200415_1924')` which as expect has ForeignKey relation defined for `profiles`

Now I've two questions,

1. Why is the first file created? (here's the [content](https://pastebin.com/NqCLXk8Q) of the first file for reference)
2. How do I export this first file into a new environment as it is present in my site-packages and not part of VCS

Because of this, I get the following error when I apply migration in my production environment

```
Migration 0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('saas', '0013_auto_20200415_1924')
```

I feel like I'm making some silly mistake, but not able to figure out what.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm researching the same issue.

Comment: @jonesy I ended up moving the entire app inside my django project, so it became a part of VCS.